# Error when using jacobian(): "Error in MuPAD command: Index exceeds matrix dimensions."

Tags: matlab

I have function F_test.m

```
function [ F_t ] = F_test( x )
F_t(1)=x(2)^2+5*x(1);
F_t(2)=x(1)+7*x(2);
end
```

I want to calculate Jacobian matrix of this function

```
[dF1/dx(1), dF2/dx(1) ; dF1/dx(2), dF2/dx(2)]
```

But when I try to do it, I get an error

```
jacobian(F_test(x),x)
Error using mupadmex
Error in MuPAD command: Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Error in sym/subsref (line 1577)
        B = mupadmex('symobj::subsref',A.s,inds{:});

Error in F_test (line 4)
F_t(1)=x(2)^2+5*x(1);
```

And even this

```
    syms x
jacobian([x(1)+x(2),x(1)*x(2)],x)
Error using mupadmex
Error in MuPAD command: Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Error in sym/subsref (line 1577)
        B = mupadmex('symobj::subsref',A.s,inds{:});
```

Answer (score 1):

Thnak, but I found how to calculate this.

```
x=sym('x',[1 2])
jacobian(F_test(x),x)
```

Answer (score 0):

For this error

```
Error in F_test (line 4)
F_t(1)=x(2)^2+5*x(1);
```

I think one of your problems may be this one:
You are doing this

```
F_t(1)=x(2)^2+5*x(1);
F_t(2)=x(1)+7*x(2);
```

but `F_t` has never been initialized in your function (unknown size)

And be sure about how to use jacobian(f,v)

http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/symbolic/jacobian.html

(Sorry, not sure, long time I haven't used MatLab)